# Flutter Mobile Slidable action styling

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, action

In my flutter mobile app I have implemented Slidable actions on a list of items using **flutter_slidable** package. But I'm unable to style them as I wanted to. I get them as 2 separate boxes with a gap, But I want them to look like in the below image;

[image]